# Css - how to change element size if it reached to certain spot on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've dynamically created some divs with random color who are scattered over the page randomly. I want to  use css to give them a condition that says that if the div is located above let's say 600px on the screen - his size will change. I know the "if" statement for css is @media but I didn't figure how to use it right in this situation. Can you help me?

Example of a div (they all have the same class - "frog")

```
<div id="frog" class="fas fa-ad" style="width: 66px; height: 66px; 
background-color: rgb(87, 58, 55); position: absolute; left: 312px; top: 
93px; display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: In the loop where you create the divs, after picking a random position, determine the size based on it.

Comment: That's strange to check position by css if you re generating random position by js.

Comment: Im going to say, you might not be able to do it with css only, you will need js.

Comment: The question says "600px" but the styling on the element is `top: 93px` so I'm a little confused by how those two relate.  If you're scrolled down 600px the element would be off screen

Comment: Hi, as I wrote - the divs are created with random left-top. This one is just an example. The idea is to give the ones who get a higher position the different size

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS only. The only way you can have dynamic styling based on what happens in the windows in CSS is to use media queries. However, [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) precise that you can only detect *window-level data*, like the device width, or whether the page is displayed on a screen or on a printed paper, etc.

You'll have to change your style with JS. This is often a bad way to have dynamic styling, because the only way to do so is to 'probe' the DOM (using for example `setInterval`). Luckily your case is an exception - since you update your divs position with JS, you can check directly after that the position of your divs, and update your styles accordingly!

Example using the very useful [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

```js
// select the frog element
let frog = document.getElementById('frog');
let count = 0;

setInterval(() => {

  // update the frog position
  frog.style.top = `${count}px`;
  count = (count+2)%200;
  
  // check if the frog is after 100px from the top of the window
  if (frog.getBoundingClientRect().top>100) {
    frog.className = 'over-100';
  } else {
    frog.className = '';
  }
  
}, 1000/30);
```

```css
#frog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
#frog.over-100 {
  background-color: olive;
}
```

```html
<div id="frog"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but kind of if statement should I write?

the name of the div is "newFrog", so my problem is - what kind of conditional should I use? 
if (newFrog > 600px) will refer to it's size, not position right?

Comment: @falcon25 I added an example